# getJSON callback after uprade to jQuery 1.5 not called

Tags: jquery

Good day!

I've running plugin on jQuery 1.4.4 with `getJSON()`, after uprade to 1.5 callback is not called. The returned JSON is valid (I've checked with validator).

Before digging more I'd like to as if this a common problem? Also I noticed additional get parameter `?callback=...` which jQuery adds to the URL

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: It seems I figured out how to create a test case and it seems that JQuery validate 1.7 (latest version) is the cause:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>

    </title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<!--    
    If I uncomment this - it will not work
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
-->
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var params = {userid : 'some-user-id-to-choose-right-temp-FTP-folder-for-the-user'};
        $.getJSON('/ajax-page_material-edit-ftp-filelist.php', params, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="clickme">Click Me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe this code in plugin is the cause:

```
// ajax mode: abort
// usage: $.ajax({ mode: "abort"[, port: "uniqueport"]});
// if mode:"abort" is used, the previous request on that port (port can be undefined) is aborted via XMLHttpRequest.abort() 
;(function($) {
    var ajax = $.ajax;
    var pendingRequests = {};
    $.ajax = function(settings) {
        // create settings for compatibility with ajaxSetup
        settings = $.extend(settings, $.extend({}, $.ajaxSettings, settings));
        var port = settings.port;
        if (settings.mode == "abort") {
            if ( pendingRequests[port] ) {
                pendingRequests[port].abort();
            }
            return (pendingRequests[port] = ajax.apply(this, arguments));
        }
        return ajax.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug:

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/#issue/36

Thanks for the response here: 
[jQuery Validate 1.7 breaks $.getJSON() on jQuery 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888226/jquery-validate-1-7-brokes-getjson-on-jquery-1-5)

Answer (score 2):

As you might know, jQuerys ajax module was almost completly rewritten. It now uses a promise maker object which fires when the new jXHR object reaches state `resolved`.

If you are calling `.getJSON()` yourself, you might try to invoke it like:

```
$.getJSON('/path/file').then(function() {
    // success
}, function() {
    // fail
});
```

If the plugin you use is calling `.getJSON()`, well thats a problem unless you can/want fix a possible problem yourself. Anyway, even if this system is new it "should" be backwards compatible.

Comment: Nice one! Too bad they didn't update the docs for `.getJSON`, I had no idea that `.getJSON` was working this way now.

Comment: @Marcus: this works on all objects which were created by `jQuery.Deferred()`.

Comment: So new implementation is not backward compatible? I haven't found this in any changelogs :(

Comment: @artvolk: it should definately be backwards compatible.

Comment: getJSON code is the same, maybe JSON parser is stricter (but I've validated my data... hm...)?

Answer (score 0):

[`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) have been changed substantially in jQuery 1.5. There is now a new object called `jqXHR` that is returned instead of `XHRHttpRequest`, but it should be backwards compatible. Unfortunately the docs for [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is outdated and still show the docs for 1.4.4. I recommend you to check the updated docs for `.ajax` instead and see if you can figure it out.

`?callback=` is added to the uri to support `jsonp` and/or cross-domain requests, so if you are doing any of this it will be added automatically.

Comment: I don't use jsonp and all my requests are to the same domain, that's why I've asked about this parameter...

Comment: @artvolk, using an absolute or relative uri?

Comment: @artvolk, interesting. could you add your request code to your question, or even better if you can get a test case running on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates this behavior?

Comment: Yep, I will prepare a test case, because now I'm sure that I haven't missed anything in changelog :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also temporarily use this hack, documented here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8084

```
//  HACK:
//    jquery-1.5 sets up jsonp for all json ajax requests
//    undo the jsonp setting here so the json requests work again
$.ajaxSetup({
    jsonp: null,
    jsonpCallback: null
});
```

Comment: It seems that updated version of jquery validate is already out.