# jQuery Validate 1.7 breaks $.getJSON() on jQuery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Good day!

I'm running a plugin on jQuery 1.4.4 with `getJSON()`, after uprade to 1.5, the callback is not called. The returned JSON is valid (I've checked with validator).

Also I noticed additional get parameter `?callback=...` which jQuery adds to the URL

It seems I figured out how to create a test case and it seems that JQuery validate 1.7 (latest version) is the cause:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>

    </title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<!--    
    If I uncomment this - it will not work
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
-->
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var params = {userid : 'some-user-id-to-choose-right-temp-FTP-folder-for-the-user'};
        $.getJSON('/ajax-page_material-edit-ftp-filelist.php', params, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="clickme">Click Me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe this code in plugin is the cause:

```
// ajax mode: abort
// usage: $.ajax({ mode: "abort"[, port: "uniqueport"]});
// if mode:"abort" is used, the previous request on that port (port can be undefined) is aborted via XMLHttpRequest.abort() 
;(function($) {
    var ajax = $.ajax;
    var pendingRequests = {};
    $.ajax = function(settings) {
        // create settings for compatibility with ajaxSetup
        settings = $.extend(settings, $.extend({}, $.ajaxSettings, settings));
        var port = settings.port;
        if (settings.mode == "abort") {
            if ( pendingRequests[port] ) {
                pendingRequests[port].abort();
            }
            return (pendingRequests[port] = ajax.apply(this, arguments));
        }
        return ajax.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The additional URL parameter `?callback=...` is for [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ticket for the issue was already created and a patch has been submitted

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/#issue/36

https://github.com/bigfix/jquery-validation/commit/9aa53f9241224ba349f9fe1b2c801be0f431b63b

Answer (score 0):

This may be already well documented, but just in case, the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888889/asp-net-mvc-3-form-not-posting-after-remote-validation/5889119#5889119) did it for me. Basically, update to jQuery Validate 1.8 and it will work with  jQuery 1.5.2. Thanks @alexander-kahoun!